# What would be the best way to store a list in a GSP page

Tags: grails, gsp

I currently have a gsp page with pagination and bulk actions based off of checkboxes. I want to store the checked item ids as the user goes to the next page, but to do so I need to store the items the user has checked. I was wondering how I could store that in the GSP page?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe use session? https://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html

Comment: could you explain a bit how i could do that to store a list?

Comment: I guess this might help, In that GSP page add a script tag and create a java script array when the user checked and unchecked update the array by using onclick function.

Comment: it's shown in the example. to store value in session you do session["user"] = "John" and to retrieve value you do session.user. since the value is stored in session it will survive between multiple independent requests.

Comment: Is the paginated data in a table? If so DataTables might help as there'd be no need to store data between pagination changes.

Comment: " I was wondering how I could store that in the GSP page?" - Why is it that you want the storage to be in the GSP page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to store the checked item ids as the user goes to the next
> page, but to do so I need to store the items the user has checked. I
> was wondering how I could store that in the GSP page?

You could store them in a GSP page simply by defining a variable in the page and assigning it a value of the ids, but that won't solve the problem you are trying to solve because that page will be gone by the time the user navigates to the next page.

Unless you are introducing some client side technology for managing state, a more common thing to do would be to submit the ids to the server and store them in a session or possibly in a database depending on the use case.